# Is a free particle describable by wave packet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

A free particle wave function can be represented as $Ae^{ikx}$, where $A$ is some constant. My understanding on the topic is free particles cannot be normalized. That is why we have to use box normalization technique. Also, I think wave-packets are resulted mathematically due to the superposition of several wave functions.
In the case of bound states, a particle is represented as a wave packet. But what happens for the free particle state?
My question is:

> Can we represent a free particle as a wave-packet? If so, which waves are being superposed here?
>   Another question is, do the wave function representing a free particle belong to the Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1):

Sure a plane wave with a definite momentum can't be normalized in infinite volume. That is why you bring up box normalization. But we certainly can make a superposition of plane waves that is normalizable and describes a free particle, it will just have a range of momenta.

Take any normalizable wave function you want and (barring some mathematical pathologies maybe) you can consider it to be a superposition of plane waves via a Fourier series. And then you can evolve it forward in time as a free particle.

Yes this normalizable wave function belongs to the Hilbert space. And no strictly speaking the plane waves themselves don't belong to the Hilbert space, but you can consider a natural extension called a rigged Hilbert space.

Comment: Can you provide some links for some rigorous understanding?

This answers the last part of my question about Hilbert space, but is a free particle equivalent to a wave packet?

Comment: Whether the particle is free or not depends on the Hamiltonian, the wavefunction (at one time) is more like an initial condition.  If you start with say the wave function for the ground state of the harmonic oscillator (a Gaussian), it will evolve differently if you use the free particle Hamiltonian ($V=0$) instead of the harmonic oscillator potential. As far as resources this is basic stuff in quantum mechanics. Maybe try Griffith's textbook chapter 2.4